# Vaadin 14 each child route uses new parentLayout every time

Tags: java, navigation, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have main AppLayout for almost all main other routes and i want to fire its constructor only once per browser tab when it is used for the first time, after this for each reroute to other child layouts i want to use previously created instance instead creating new AppLayout. I added annotation PreserveToRefresh but this didn't help. It only use same AppLayout when i refresh again last created route. When I'm using rerouteTo(AppLayout.class) in my child layout then it is correctly navigating to my old instance but becouse of that i added AppLayout as parent in route annotation constructor is fired anyway but new instance is not used.

Is it possible to route to old instance of parent layout without using rerouteTo in each children without creating new instance each reroute?

I'm using Vaadin 14.8.14.
My Routes to reproduce:
MainRoute:

```
@Route( value = "testMainPage") 
@UIScope
@PreserveOnRefresh
@Push
    public class TestMainPanel extends AppLayout {
        public TestMainPanel() {
            DrawerToggle toggle = new DrawerToggle();
            H1 title = new H1("MyApp");
            addToNavbar(toggle, title);
            System.out.println("New Instance of TestMainPanel");    
        }   
    }
```

Child2:

```
@Route(layout = TestMainPanel.class, value = "testChildRoute")
@UIScope    
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class TestChildRoute extends Div{
    private Label testChildLabel;
    public TestChildRoute() {
        testChildLabel = new Label("Test Child Route Label");
        add(testChildLabel);
    }
}
```

ChildRoute2:
@PreserveOnRefresh
@Route(layout = TestMainPanel.class, value = "testChildRoute2")
public class TestChildRoute2 extends Div{
private Label testChildLabel;
public TestChildRoute2() {
testChildLabel = new Label("Test Child Route Label2");
add(testChildLabel);
}
}

Each time when i'm changing route between testChildRoute and testChildRoute2 then every time TestMainPanel constructor is fired.

StackTrace fired in my AppLayout constructor:

```
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1336)
at pl.ada.web.app.views.panel.MainPanel.<init>(MainPanel.java:120)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:212)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1216)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:321)
at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator.getOrCreate(SpringInstantiator.java:117)
at com.vaadin.flow.di.Instantiator.createRouteTarget(Instantiator.java:165)
at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.lambda$getRouteTarget$1(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:139)
at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.getRouteTarget(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:138)
at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.sendBeforeEnterEventAndPopulateChain(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:528)
at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.createChainIfEmptyAndExecuteBeforeEnterNavigation(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:508)
at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:225)
at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.handleNavigation(Router.java:261)
at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:232)
at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.navigate(Router.java:198)
at com.vaadin.flow.router.Router.initializeUI(Router.java:95)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.initializeUIWithRouter(BootstrapHandler.java:1634)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.createAndInitUI(BootstrapHandler.java:1627)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(BootstrapHandler.java:508)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1579)
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:252)
at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: The parent layout is supposed to be reused by default, but there's nothing in your description that would give me any clues for why that doesn't work in your case. Could you make the constructor in your parent layout print the stacktrace and share that here?

Comment: Of course, i added it in question. I thought the same when i was reading about parent layout but after i implemented it then it was working contrary to the description

Comment: What's on line 120 in MainPanel?

Comment: Thread.dumpStack(); to print this stakctrace

Comment: Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is that the stacktrace from the initial rendering when the instance is supposed to be created, or a subsequent navigation when it's supposed to be reused? I'm asking because it looks like the initial one. Of it's not, then the problem is that each navigation creates a new UI which in turn circumvents any reuse.

Comment: This is stacktrace that was fired when second instance of parent layout was created by routing in the same browser tab. I added simple code to reproduce where the same problem arises.